# Object Cast Error

Tags: c#

In My AddProduct Method there is something wrong with my code. I get a message saying Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other Types when I test my code. Anybody have any ideas where this problem is coming from?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
 namespace ProductMaintenance
{
class ProductDB
{

    public static Product GetProduct(string code)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
        string select = "SELECT ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice "
           + "FROM Products "
           + "WHERE ProductCode = @ProductCode";
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(select, connection);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", code);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader prodReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (prodReader.Read())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.Code = prodReader["ProductCode"].ToString(); ;
                product.Description = prodReader["Description"].ToString();
                product.Price = ((decimal)prodReader["Price"]);
                return product;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    public static bool UpdateProduct(Product oldProduct, Product newProduct)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
        string updateStatement = "UPDATE Products SET " + "Description = @NewDescription, " + "UnitPrice = @NewUnitPrice, " + "WHERE ProductCode = @oldProductCode " + "AND Description = @OldDescription " + "AND UnitPrice = @OldUnitPrice";
        SqlCommand updateCommand =
            new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NewDescription", newProduct.Description);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@NewUnitPrice", newProduct.Price);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldProductCode", oldProduct.Code);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldDescription", oldProduct.Description);
        updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
            "@OldUnitPrice", oldProduct.Price);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int count = updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(count > 0)

                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    public static int AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = MMABooksDB.GetConnection();
        string insertStatement = "INSERT Products " + "(ProductCode, Description, UnitPrice) " + "VALUES (@ProductCode, @Description, @UnitPrice)";
        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, connection);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", product.Code);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", product.Description);
        insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", product.Price);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string selectStatement = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Products') FROM Products";
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);
            int productC = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());

            return productC;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you need to check for null before casting. always.

Comment: You get a message? On what line, where? What values are you using?

Comment: The error message means what it says.  If there is no data for one of the columns the reader will return DbNull. You cant cast or convert it to use ToString on it.

Comment: My eye was drawn to the same thing. But the question says that the exception is coming from `AddProduct` which doesn't contain a `SqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting `IDENT_CURRENT` which can possibly return null.

See [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx).

> Returns NULL on error or if a caller does not have permission to view
>   the object.
>
> In SQL Server, a user can only view the metadata of
>   securables that the user owns or on which the user has been granted
>   permission. This means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such
>   as IDENT_CURRENT may return NULL if the user does not have any
>   permission on the object.

Based on the error you're describing, this appears to be where it's failing. Your `AddProduct` method wouldn't be trying to cast a null value when it does the `INSERT` so it is likely a null value when you try to retrieve the identity at

```
int productC = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Since the call to `IDENT_CURRENT` is the only statement in that SQL command, that all but rules out a syntax or other error in the SQL, which would narrow this down to permissions.

There's a bit of conjecture and deduction there but I suspect that's where it's at.

(If the error is thrown from `AddProduct` method there's no need to post everything else. Many people - including myself - are going to jump to the conclusion that the error is when you access the `SqlDataReader` since you aren't checking for nulls there. But as you said, that's not the method throwing the exception. It's just easy to miss when there's so much irrelevant code.)